# Axis2-ParseError: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[-1,-1]

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis, webservices-client

I have an Axis2 service running under Tomcat 7. I get the Axis Error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[-1,-1]
Message: Invalid encoding name "".
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:122)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:347)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:414)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150)
    at com.identitysystems.www.xmlschema.iss_version_10.syncronizer.ListasRestringidassyncStub.iDT_Nocturnosync(ListasRestringidassyncStub.java:203)
    at com.identitysystems.www.xmlschema.iss_version_10.syncronizer.CallClient.main(CallClient.java:27)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[-1,-1]
Message: Invalid encoding name "".
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.common.factory.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createXMLStreamReader(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.common.factory.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:228)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:542)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:521)
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:203)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:107)
    ... 7 more
```